# Sugar-free chewy texture with a starch or hydrocolloid

Tags: starch, sugar-free

I would like to create a chewy sugar-free (keto) cookie.

Which ingredient (probably a starch or hydrocolloid) can emulate the chewiness of a cookie made with brown sugar, without sugar?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would not expect a starch to be the answer in a Keto cookie since starches are treated the same as sugar in most low carb diets

Comment: I actually think this could be a good question, but what research have you done? I Googled chewy keto cookies just now and got multiple recipe hits. What have you tried and why were you dissatisfied with those results?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use honey, but there are other options, like

- allulose
- xilitol
- Maple syrup

Comment: Honey is [basically just sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#Nutrition), so if the OP is trying to avoid processed sugar, great, but if they're aiming for keto or avoiding sugars in general, it's no help